# what is the best way to update status bar message?

Tags: c#, statusbar

May i know which is the best way to update a statusbar message in MDI application.I have come across this code for displaying the message in status bar of parent form from child form but i want to update the message based on user's action.
In parent form

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FrmShiftManagement newMDIChild = new FrmShiftManagement();
        newMDIChild.MdiParent = this;
        this.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.Cascade);
        newMDIChild.Show();

        StatusMessage.Text = "Ready";

        //toolstriplabel1.Alignment = ToolStripItemAlignment.Right;
    }



 public void ShowStatus(string status)
    {
        this.StatusMessage.Text = status;
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
```

In Child form

```
((FrmTRMS)this.MdiParent).ShowStatus("Item(s) Saved");
```

This code is working fine when the data is saved or any action performed..Now how can i set parent form original message back to the status bar once the data is saved or deleted.

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulties with?

Comment: Delegates and events should help you!

Comment: You seem to be changing it after saving right now (based on past tense used)

Comment: I don't like that `Application.DoEvents()`. What's that for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution w.r.to display message from child form to parent form in statusbar..I have gone through this link..http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/pass_data_between_forms.aspx
its very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
string oldMsg = "";
public void ShowStatus(string status)
{
    oldMsg = this.StatusMessage.Text;
    this.StatusMessage.Text = status;
    this.StatusMessage.Invalidate(); // To force status bar redraw
    this.StatusMessage.Refresh();
}

public void RestoreStatus()
{
    this.StatusMessage.Text = oldMsg;
}
```

and use `RestoreStatus()` on child form close or whenever you please.

Comment: Hi..i have tried to use your code but it is not displaying Refresh method for StatusMessage..

Comment: @Nazima: Refresh() is inside every windowed control, so if StatusMessage is a status bar it should have Refresh method.